# Moving dog from warm to cold climate

Tags: dogs, winter, weather

We recently adopted a rescue dog from Houston and we live in Colorado. He's never experienced a cold winter and for sure not one like Colorado gets. Given that adopted him so close to winter will his body know to adjust and develop his winter coat?  Or will that be a change that happens next year after he's adapted to living in Colorado?

Thanks!

Comment: What breed of dog, or more specifically, what type of coat does he have?

Comment: We think border collie/cattle dog mix. He's got a short, oily coat.

Comment: We get dogs from Texas, Alabama, etc here in Minnesota all the time. He should be just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations and thank you for adopting a dog!

**Kindly tell us if you plan to keep your dog inside your home, or outside.** Assuming inside, I think your dog will tell you, and no need to worry, especially if anything close to a Collie! Just put special notice to the **paws!** - if your dogs, unlike mine, are OK with "shoes" please put them on during walks when it is really cold.

P.S. I am now in Japan, with two circa 15-year-old mixed-breed abandoned dogs adopted in Shanghai. When living in Finland in between, one of them (probably mixture between Shih Tzu and Maltese) had trouble as his personality did not allow the shoes which was funny, so during the winter walks I often had to stop, take away my gloves, and carry him while warming up his paws with my hands.

Answer (score -1):

I moved a Shepard mix from Houston to northern IL. It is a house dog but she loved outside walks and her fur grew thicker quickly ( moved in Jan.)